# Extreme weather dataset for all countries from 2008 to 2011

Tags: data-request, weather

Where could I find the dataset for Geographical Hot Spots (Hurricanes, Tsunami, Earth quakes, Floods etc) associated with each countries?

Comment: Can we rename the title to "Extreme Weather"?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you are interested in: http://weather.unisys.com/hurricane/atlantic/2014/index.php It's only about hurricanes and unfortunately there are single files for each hurricane with LatLon data. So really accurate but not easily listable by country.

Answer (score 5):

Addressing partly your question:

The NOAA has a [Significant Earthquake database](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/nndc/struts/form?t=101650&s=1&d=1) that can be downloaded in CSV format. The dataset also indicates if the earthquake event was linked to a tsunami.

Answer (score 3):

Once again a partial answer...

The Dartmouth Flood Observatory (now housed at the University of Colorado instead of Dartmouth) maintains a list of large remotely sensed flood events going back to 1985 with countries. Download the excel sheet to see the full set.

http://floodobservatory.colorado.edu/Archives/index.html